# Selenium can´t interact element by id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm experimenting with selenium a little bit the last time and ran into this issue. On this [website](https://www.heinemann-shop.com/de/global/tamnavulin/tamnavulin-single-malt-whisky-oloroso-cask-40vol-1l/p/000000000001512691/) selenium can't interact any elements by id or classes I tried to switch to another frame and tried waiting for it with 
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "home_delivery"))` nothing worked has anybody any idea how to fix this thanks in advance. I get this error `could not be scrolled into view`.

Comment: There's a difference between "not finding an element" and "the element can be found but is not clickable". Are you sure you can't **find** it?

Comment: can you post the ss of elemnt which you want to scrape

Comment: I get this error `could not be scrolled into view`. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a parenthesis?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "home_delivery"))
```

should be:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "home_delivery")))
```

Otherwise, your steps seem to follow other's recommended structures (https://programtalk.com/python-examples/selenium.webdriver.support.EC.element_to_be_clickable/) and radio buttons are definitely "clickable" (https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-radio-buttons/)

So I am hoping this is just a simple typo problem?

Comment: No unfortunately it was not a typo. But thanks for your help.